# How to make styling NgComponent work in Chrome/Firefox,

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a Angular Component

```dart
@NgComponent(
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  template: r''' ... some markup ...''',
  cssUrl: 'packages/myapp/components/mycomponent/mycomponent.css'
)
class MyComponent {
}
```

The `mycomponent.css` contains a bunch of styles like

```dart
:host div.someclass {
  border: 3px solid #aeaeae;
  /*... and some other */
}
```

The `index.html` contains

```dart
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
    <!-- shadow_dom.min.js doesn't work with firefox
         https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues/372 
       <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"> -->
</head>
```

This works fine in Dartium.

When I run `pub build` and run the result **in Chrome or Firefox all styles are ignored**.
Inspect element shows in Chrome and Firefox that a style tag containing all styles was added to the first child of the `<mycomponent>` tag.

What am I missing to make this work in other browsers than Dartium?

Comment: Could you put this into a github gist or similar where one can easily get it?

Comment: So you don't think there is something obvious missing/wrong? I try to create a small project reproducing the problem.

Comment: there might be, I used NgComponents and don't remember having issues in Chrome. I think I ran FF too, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Did you include shadow dom dependency in your pubspec.yaml and added <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script> in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing dependency on shadow dom in your pubspec file (`shadow_dom: any`). You also need script in your html (`<script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>`). I tried running samples form angular.dart.tutorial project, specifically Chapter_04 and it works just fine in Chrome and FF.

Comment: I have the dependency and script and it is loaded successfully in these browsers. I'll take a look at the tutorial, this is a great idea. I was not aware that it has a styles NgComponent.

Comment: The angular.dart.tutorial component examples don't use the `:host` selector. Maybe my understanding when to use `:host` is wrong, but it works in Dartium.

Comment: I think I have overused the `:host` selector. Your suggestion with the angular.dart.tutorial helped me solve it - I read http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/ again. I still wonder why this worked in Dartium though.

Comment: If I remember correctly, :host is obsolete. You need to use @host.

Comment: It was the other way. @host is obsolet. :host is the way to go, but I used it too much. It is only necessary to style the element itself not  the elements in the shadowDOM.

Comment: Yes. Your styles which apply to elements inside shadowRoot should be under shadowRoot itself, inside a style tag. I suggest reading ShadowDom 101 on html5rocks. If you look carefully you will notice that styles are inside template tag which is then put into shadowRoot element. Anyways glad you worked it out.